# Understanding Hypergeometric and Negative Binomial random variables

Tags: probability

On Wednesday afternoons, eight men play tennis on two courts. They know ahead of time which four will play on the north court and which four will play on the south court. The players arrive randomly at the tennis courts. What is the probability that the first four players that arrive are all assigned to (a) the north court, and (b) the same court?

Why do we use a hypergeometric distribution here given that in (a) we're asked to find the probability that the first four players that arrive are all assigned to the north court? My understanding is that if we have independent Bernoulli trials, each with the same probability of success p, and if X is the number of trials required to obtain the rth success, then X is a negative binomial random variable with parameters r and p.

Can we say that trial = player arrives at tennis courts? So for the 4th trial to be the last success we have X ~ NB(4,1/2)?

The correct approach is to assume that all eight people are assigned to one of the two courts whereby 4 are assigned to the north court and 4 are assigned to the south court. The idea is to choose four of them, at random, without replacement and assume that they have arrived at the session first. So if we let X = # of players assigned to the north court. Then pmf of X is $P(X=x)=\frac{{4 \choose x}{4 \choose 4-x}}{8 \choose 4}$

$\therefore P(X=4)=\frac{1}{70}$.

Would you please provide an explanation as to why we use HG instead of NB here, and in general, what to look for when deciding to choose between the two? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the binomial and negative binomial  distributions, the **probability is constant from trial to trial.**

For the hypergeometric distribution, **probability changes from trial to trial as there is no replacement.**

Based on the clear demarcation spelt out above, it should be evident that for this problem, you need to use the hypergeometric distribution.